# Camel FluentProducerTemplate required Maven pom dependency

Tags: apache-camel

Can someone clarify which specific ***Maven pom file dependency*** is required for the Camel **FluentProducerTemplate** ...I have tried camel-cdi and cdi-api.

I've trolled many examples and think I know how to use, just not which specific dependency to reference in my pom file.

Comment: It's definetly in `camel-core`, from version 2.18.0 according to docs: http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html

Comment: Thanks ...I must be using a release of Core without the template.